# Cursor does not go begining of the line

Tags: terminal, console, cursor

Hello I am trying to go begining of the line. neither left arrow key or ctrl + a 
lets me do it. everytime it keeps couple letters on the right.
however its a visual bug my cursor is actually in the begining

I am not exactly sure why it happens but it happen both on default terminal app and iterm2

[image]

[image]

P.S : it isnt only happens with this command I just didnt know what else to write to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That issue is related to your $PS1, you're probably missing some escape character.
This one should work:

`PS1="\[\e[1;31m\]\u[\w]$\[\e[0m\] "`